# What's the expected stopping time for a sum of random variables to cross a threshold?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I have a sequence of non-negative identically (and I believe independently) distributed random variables $X_i$. I know their expectation $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X_i]$. And I'm waiting for the sum to cross some threshold $t$. Define the stopping time $\tau$ as
$$
\tau = \min_k : \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \geq t\,.
$$
Then what's the expectation of $\tau$? Intuitively it should be
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau] = \frac{t}{\mu}\,.
$$
But I'm not entirely convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is generally referred to as Wald's Equation or more generally Wald's Theorem. The assumptions are that $E[|X_1|]<\infty$ and $E[\tau]<\infty$. You can find a [proof here](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-ST.pdf).

Comment: But note that Wald's equation does not quite imply that $E[\tau]$ equals $t/\mu$, because $\sum_{t=1}^\tau X_i$ can exceed $t$.  Consider the case that the $X_i$'s are even integers.  Then the two cases $t=2$ or $t=3$ are actually equivalent, so yield the same expectation of $\tau$.  But $2/\mu \ne 3/\mu$.

Comment: What if $\mu = 0$?

Comment: @user3141592 Note that this is a martingale. Assume X has $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$. , then the partial sum $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is a martingale, and then by the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem), the expected value of $M_\tau$ is 0. Use then that $Y_n = M_{n}^{2} - n\sigma$ is also a martingale, and we can use $0 = \mathbb{E}[Y_0] = \mathbb{E}[Y_\tau] = t^2 - \mathbb{E}[\tau]\sigma$, which gives $\mathbb{E}[\tau] = t^2 / \sigma$. Note this is the two-sided stopping time (i.e. -t or +t), doesnt work for one sided.