# An expected increasing stochastic will stop if exceeding a threshold. What's the stopping time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stopping-times

I have a non-negative stochastic process $X_1, X_2, ...$ with expected increasing value, i.e., $E[X_{i+1}|X_{i}]=c \cdot X_{i}$ where $c>1$.

This process start with $X_1=a$ and will stop once $X_T>b$ for some time $T$. $(b>a)$

I want to know the expected stopping time of this process. My intuition tell me that the expected stopping time is $\log_c \frac{b}{a}$. But I cannot find any proof for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of $T$ is not necessarily given by $\log_c \frac ba$, and in fact does not need to be finite.  For example, let $Y_n$ be iid random variables with $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=2b) = \frac{c}{2b}$, $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0) = 1-\frac{c}{2b}$.  I'm assuming $c < 2b$ here, but the example can be easily modified if that is not the case.

Note that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = c$, so if we let $X_1 = a$ and $X_i := \prod_{n=2}^i Y_n$ then $X_i$ satisfies your properties by independence.  However, we can directly compute the distribution of your stopping time since $X_i$ either passes $b$ immediately or never passes $b$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(T = 2) &= \frac{c}{2b} \\
\mathbb{P}(T = \infty) &= 1-\frac{c}{2b}.
\end{align*}
Since $T = \infty$ with positive probability, $\mathbb{E}[T] = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very helpful.

Comment: I am still thinking about what if $E[T]<\infty$. I notice some other answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788123/whats-the-expected-stopping-time-for-a-sum-of-random-variables-to-cross-a-thres) claiming that the (modified) Wald's Equation can prove such a result.

Comment: @PolluxCong It would be best to ask that as a separate question, but I don't believe it would hold in that case either.